# Python 3 and Azure table storage tablestorageaccount not working

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to use the sample provided by Microsoft to connect to an Azure storage table using Python. The code below fail because of tablestorageaccount not found. What I'm missing I installed the azure package but still complaining that it's not found.

```
import azure.common
from azure.storage import CloudStorageAccount
from tablestorageaccount import TableStorageAccount

print('Azure Table Storage samples for Python')

# Create the storage account object and specify its credentials 
# to either point to the local Emulator or your Azure subscription
if IS_EMULATED:
    account = TableStorageAccount(is_emulated=True)
else:
    account_connection_string = STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
    # Split into key=value pairs removing empties, then split the pairs into a dict
    config = dict(s.split('=', 1) for s in account_connection_string.split(';') if s)

    # Authentication
    account_name = config.get('AccountName')
    account_key = config.get('AccountKey')
    # Basic URL Configuration
    endpoint_suffix = config.get('EndpointSuffix')
    if endpoint_suffix == None:
       table_endpoint  = config.get('TableEndpoint')
       table_prefix = '.table.'
       start_index = table_endpoint.find(table_prefix)
       end_index = table_endpoint.endswith(':') and len(table_endpoint) or table_endpoint.rfind(':')
       endpoint_suffix = table_endpoint[start_index+len(table_prefix):end_index]
    account = TableStorageAccount(account_name = account_name, connection_string = account_connection_string, endpoint_suffix=endpoint_suffix)
```

Comment: Can you share the link from where you’ve taken the code?

Comment: Suppose you are using this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-python-getting-started), and in this sample `tablestorageaccount ` is a custom module.Check here.https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-python-getting-started/blob/master/tablestorageaccount.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the source sample code, and in the sample code there is still a custom module `tablestorageaccount.py`, it's just used to return `TableService`. If you already have the storage connection string and want to have a test, you could connect to table directly.

Sample:

```
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

account_connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account name;AccountKey=account key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'

tableservice=TableService(connection_string=account_connection_string)
```

[image]

Also you could refer to the new sdk to connect table. Here is the official tutorial about [Get started with Azure Table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-python?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: OMG! Thanks! This is so simple! Yes with my connection string and your suggestion I'm now able to connect to my tables and do queries!